# Magento 3column phtml edit doesn't not undo

Tags: php, magento

I am new to magento. I went to go to this url

```
/public_html/app/design/frontend/default/modern/template/page
```

and I edited the page 3columns.phtml. I just put "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" to test, is it the default homepage. When I refreshed the homepage, the string of a's show above appeared on homepage. Then, I came to know this is the default homepage. Now, I removed the string, and saved the page, but the string doesn't disappear from the home page when I open it. Here is the code, you can see that I have remove the string, but still it's effect is there on homepage. How to fix this problem?

Here is the code where you can see the output string at the top.

```
http://spacedookie.com/
```

and here is hte code. Please help me to solve this problem

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="<?php echo $this->getLang() ?>" lang="<?php echo $this->getLang() ?>">
<head>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('head') ?>
</head>
<body<?php echo $this->getBodyClass()?' class="'.$this->getBodyClass().'"':'' ?>>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('after_body_start') ?>
<div class="wrapper">
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_notices') ?>
<div class="page">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('header') ?>
    <div class="main-container col2-left-layout">
        <div class="main">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') ?>
            <?php /*<div class="col-wrapper">*/ ?>
                <div class="col-main">
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>
                </div>
                <div class="col-left sidebar"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('left') ?>    </div>
            </div>
            <?php /*<div class="col-right sidebar"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('right') ?></div>*/ ?>
        <?php /*</div>*/ ?>
    </div>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer') ?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('before_body_end') ?>
</div>
</div>
    <?php echo $this->getAbsoluteFooter() ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: did you disable cache through admin ?

Comment: @programmer_rkt do, i didn't. I don't know about cache.

Comment: ok login admin. then go to `system->cache management`. There you need to select all items and disable them. Then go to root directory of installation and find `var/cache` directory. Clear all data inside it. Then refresh your page.

Comment: did it work ? Inform me please

Comment: @programmer_rkt clearing all data in var/cache means deleting all folders? If I delete them, will it have any bad effect? How are these folders created? If they are created automatically, how?

Comment: I didn't try it yet, I don't have access to admin panel. I messaged to  my client to provide me access. When they provide me, I will give it a try.

Comment: yes you need to delete all foders inside that. Magento adds those files in order to increase the speed of you site. I will give you an idea if it fixes your issue. Its not going to  make any problems to your site.

Comment: var/cache sub-folders are automagically created by Magento. Delete without fear.

Comment: ok. when i get admin access, i will give a try and will post reply here accordingaly.

Comment: @MuhammadSohail : see my answer. you will get an idea

Answer (score 0):

It is most probably cache issue. Magento automatically adds cache, once you loaded a page. This is because, when we try to load a page in magento, there happends enormous amount of processing by Magento.

I cant provide the whole process that happens in backside. In short I will give you an overview. Magento will first identify Module that holds the controller/method that is described by the url. After that it starts to loads the `layout tree` corresponding to the url requested. Believe me it is a huge tree !!!. After loaded the entire layout, it starts to render those layout. (Layout holds blocks. Those blocks may be parents for some other blocks, then these child blocks may hold other child blocks and so on). So magento probably take lot of time to load it. So it use an easy way to overcome it. **CACHE** (However cache has also limitations).

So when a page is loaded once, it will also set some cache. When it came to load the same page again, it will first check data in cache first. If data is there, then it will use cache to load that page. This will  the speed up loading of magnento site, since it doesn't load the entire layout tree and thus make our site user friendly.

However when development is going on your site, it is important to disable this feature. Other wise, we couldn't see the changes that we made.

We can disable cache through admin. go to `System -> Cache Management`. Then select all items and then disable it. Then go to `var/cache` directory (which is in your root directory) and clear all folder/files in there. Deleting these folder/files will not cause any issues to your site.

Comment: ok. the client took much time to reply. so, i installed magento on my local host. Now I want to do the same changes into the home page file and when the problem arises, i will try your method to solve it. But, i don't know which theme currently the magento has activated. I installed magento freshly, what is the default theme so that i can edit the file.

Comment: by default the theme package is set to `default`. However theme is not set by magento by default. So magento assumes theme as `default`. So where you need  to change is `app/design/frontend/default/default/`. but fresh install doesnt contain any layout in that directory. What you need to do is copy content in `app/design/frontend/base/default/` to that location and then edit files in default. This way base templates/layout files get untouched.

Comment: Please do some research on magento. Especially how to configure magento through admin. Then try to solve problems

Comment: Hi, I remove the string from top now. But now the problem is, the site is not reverting back to its original state. You can see here http://spacedookie.com/ this was not the actual home page, the home page was something else. How to revert back the original home page?